# Using a él in a sentence with lo

Tags: objetos-directos

I found the following sentence in my textbook:

> Lo espero **a él**

As far as I know doesn't it mean something like "Him I wait for him"? Why is **a él** necessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not necessary. You can say:

> Lo espero

But its not clear. What "Lo" means?

- Is it a persorn?
- Is it an object?

> ¿Te ha llegado el correo?
>
> No, todavía lo espero.

- Is it an action?

> ¿Vas a aprobar este examen?
>
> Lo espero

Comment: You're right. In a sentence like the following "a él" removes a possible ambiguity: _-¿A quién amas realmente, a Juan o a su dinero? -Lo amo a él._

Answer (score 0):

When you use **él** (him), you refer to a person. For example:

> Lo que diga **él**. (What HE says)
>
> Dile **a él**. (Tell HIM)

When you use **el** is a definite article used before a noun if it is masculine such as **la** if it is feminine.

> El carro. **The car**
>
> La guitarra. **The guitar**

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - *"Pedro"* **lo espero a él**

-

> 2 - *"Marta"* **lo espero a él**

-

> 3 - *"El perro"* **lo espero a él**

---

Who is **"el"**?, él is a masculine person.

él is no nessesary, but, is gramaticaly correct.