# Dile a él - pronoun necessary

Tags: uso-de-palabras, pronombres

I take it from [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14929/using-a-%C3%A9l-in-a-sentence-with-lo/14942#14942) that when saying something like

> Dile a él ...

The *a él* part is not necessary and can be left out, it is just for clarification.

Now I am wondering if I could just leave out the *le*. Besides the fact, that it sounds clumsy, are the following three phrases the same?

> - Dile ...
> - Dile a él ...
> - Di a él ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Dile* is sufficent and the more correct form, *dile a él* is more enfatic, you want to use this form to avoid ambiguity, because *dile* can mean *dile (a él)* as well as *dile (a ella)*.

*Di a él* is not correct. When an explicit object (direct or indirect) is a pronoun (mí, ti, vos, él, ella, Vd., nosotros, nosotras, vosotros, vosotras, ellos, ellas, Vds.), it is obligatory to use the corresponding unstressed object pronoun (so the unstressed pronoun, or both, but not just the explicit).

Comment: Nicely explained! I wondered if _Di a él_ was correct or not, because it sounds strange to me.

Comment: @fedorqui *Di a él* is not correct.  When an explicit object (direct or indirect) is a pronoun (mí, ti, vos, él, ella, Vd., nosotros, nosotras, vosotros, vosotras, ellos, ellas, Vds.), it is obligatory to use the corresponding unstressed object pronoun (so the unstressed pronoun, or both, but not just the explicit).  For any other object, you can use either or both.

Comment: @guifa thaks a lot for the clarification. I have added it into the answer.