# How to say "He likes football"?

Tags: traducción, españa

I am trying to tell someone (via email) that my friend likes football (English football i.e. soccer) but I'm not sure which one of these it would be.

Is it

> A él le gusta el fútbol

or just

> Le gusta el fútbol

Comment: Both are valid. The differences are the same as seen in [this question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18815/12637).

Comment: As explained in the question @CarlosAlejo links, use the first expression if you want to emphasize that it is him who likes football and not someone else (e.g.: *A él le gusta el fútbol y a ella, el baloncesto*). Otherwise, just use the second one (e.g. *- ¿Qué le gusta a Juan? - Le gusta el fútbol.*)

Answer (score 1):

Saying "A él le gusta el fútbol" you are being more accurate (HE likes football).

With "Le gusta el fútbol" you can refer to woman or man.

Comment: This can be a thing, but I mainly agree with what Gorpik suggested regarding the emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with these answers. Both mean the same thing and are correct, however 'a él...' is more emphatic and I would use this perhaps in a comparison to show clarity such as:

> A mí me gusta el baloncesto pero a él le gusta el fútbol

This means "As for me, I like basketball but when it comes to him, he likes football".